# Disabling Hybrid Boot In Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, hybrid-boot

Hybrid boot is a process that speeds up the normal startup in Windows 8 (apparently it makes booting faster than in previous versions of Windows)

The normal boot usually looks like this:

**Pre-boot -> System Initialization -> User Session Initialization**

The hybrid boot looks like this:

**Pre-boot -> Hiberfile read -> Driver Initialization -> User Session Initialization**

Windows 8 hybrid boot takes the concept of hibernating your computer to boot your system. When you hibernate, your system takes a snapshot of the **System Initialization** for that session to use when it wakes up. This creates a **hiberfil** with that session data saved which Windows 8 then uses to wake up from that hibernation.

I wish to **disable Hybrid Boot in Windows 8** (as I have read it may cause problems such as the PC to hang at startup) even if the boot time is slightly increased (as it never really bothered me in Windows 7 etc) and would appreciate guidance on how to achieve this ?

Comment: How to Do a Full Shutdown in Windows 8 Without Disabling Hybrid Boot- http://www.howtogeek.com/129021/how-to-do-a-full-shutdown-in-windows-8-without-disabling-hybrid-boot/

Comment: i knew it, but, i thought it might someday help somebody.

Comment: Disabling hybrid boot may also be useful when using Linux along Windows in a multi-boot environment, as it may cause problems in Linux (hdd drives not accessible)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a great tutorial at [hecticgeek](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/12/disable-hybrid-boot-windows-8/) how you can disable the hybrid boot permanently.

> 1. Open ‘Control Panel’ and search for the below term.
>
>    `change what power buttons do` 
>    This should open the ‘Power Options’ icon and then click on the link below it called ‘Change what
>      the power buttons do’ to open the configuration page. 
>      [image]
> 2. Now, at the top of this page, if you can see a blue text link called ‘Change settings that are currently unavailable’ (shown below),
>      then click on it first, otherwise you won’t be able to change those
>      settings. 
>    [image]
> 3. Then simply scroll down and under the sub-heading ‘Shutdown settings’, remove the check mark of the option called ‘Turn on fast
>      start-up (recommended)‘. Then click on the ‘Save changes’ button below
>      to close the window and apply the changes. 
>      [image: enter imagedescription here]

[Source](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/12/disable-hybrid-boot-windows-8/)

Comment: Very concise article and thankyou for highlighting the main points.

Comment: You are welcome. :) You can also temporarily disable it by running `shutdown /p`in run-dialog. But I think you will disable it permanently. :)

Answer (score 2):

> **Command-line methods** (faster for me):

To **disable** Fast Boot:

1- Open [elevated](https://superuser.com/questions/728810/how-do-you-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7-with-a-shortcut-key/728824#728824) command-line prompt.
2- Disable **Fast Boot**:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /V HiberbootEnabled /T REG_dWORD /D 0 /F
```

3- Disable **Hibernation**:

```
powercfg /h off
```

---

To **re-enable** Fast Boot:

1- Open [elevated](https://superuser.com/questions/728810/how-do-you-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-7-with-a-shortcut-key/728824#728824) command-line prompt.
2- Enable **Hibernation** (precondition):

```
powercfg /h on
```

3- Enable **Fast Boot**:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power" /V HiberbootEnabled /T REG_dWORD /D 1 /F
```