# Disabling Hybrid Shutdown In Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, shutdown, hybrid-boot

Following on from asking [Disabling Hybrid Boot In Windows 8 ?](https://superuser.com/questions/656459/disabling-hybrid-boot-in-windows-8) and reviewing [Are there downsides to Windows 8 Hybrid Shutdown ?](https://superuser.com/questions/496241/are-there-downsides-to-windows-8-hybrid-shutdown) and knowing that Windows 8 will always perform a **Hybrid Shutdown** by default.

I would like to know how to perform a **normal** (full) shutdown from the Windows 8 tiled start screen **(by disabling hybrid shutdown**).

As far as I can tell there are **no settings** that will allow this (**unlike with disabling hybrid boot**), and therefore am guessing a shortcut is required to achieve this ?

*Please Note: As far as I'm aware generally speaking Hybrid Booting and Shutdown is perfectly fine in most cases, except when you are experiencing Windows 8 hanging upon restart and hence therefore the reasons for wanting to perform a normal shutdown (and boot) to correct this (hopefully).*

Comment: Doesn't disabling hybrid boot also does what you want (as disabling either of these would make the second one useless)? If you aren't booting from suspended kernel et al, then you don't need to suspend it on every shutdown, that's what logic suggests.

Comment: @DragoonPL1 Yes I understand your logic, but thats if you have done a disablement of hybrid boot to start with ?

Comment: Ah, I get it now. You want to disable Hybrid Boot once, not by default. Chris' answer is okay - just create a shortcut with `shutdown /s /full /t 0`, change an icon (if you want), and pin it to the Start Screen. (Place it somewhere, where you can search for it in Metro, then R-Click > Pin to Start).

Comment: @DragoonPL1 Yes thats the comment I just made to Chris :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this command you can force windows to make a full shutdown immediately, with no time delay(0 seconds). Next time you start the system there will be a full system initialization.
You can make a bat-script for example.

```
shutdown /s /full /t 0
```

Or you temporarily disable the hybrid with:

```
shutdown /p
```

**If you want to add it to metro do the following:**

1. At the Desktop -->Right-click --> New --> Shortcut
2. Put the line of code int the **location**-field.
3. Click Next
4. Name it however you want.
5. Click Finish.
6. Paste the shortcut into the following directory:
   `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
7. Now you see a tile on the start-screen.
8. Now you can shutdown your computer by clicking on it.

**If you want to change the icon, do the following:**

1. Right-click the shortcut --> Properties
2. Open the shortcut-tab
3. Click `Change icon`
4. Click `okay` on the next dialog. This happens, because the shortcut hasn't already an icon.
5. Now choose an icon.
6. Click Ok.
7. Your shortcut has now an icon.

For a really detailed tutorial go to [Howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/77061/how-to-add-shutdown-restart-sleep-to-the-windows-8-metro-start-screen/)

Comment: Thanks for that Chris. Is there anyway to put a shortcut tile on the start screen (for simplicity sake) ?

Comment: Edited my answer. You can add a shortcut and stick it to metro. You can assign the shutdown-code as path. that should work

Comment: Thanks for that and i'm guessing just rename the tile "Full Shutdown".

Comment: You can rename it, however you want. The path is the important thing.

Comment: If you want to change the icon, i've added this to my answer. :)