# Windows-Linux multi-boot problems in case of upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, linux, multi-boot, grub2, windows-10-upgrade

I use Windows 7 on a multiple-boot machine (beside Win7, I have different Linuxes, using Grub).

I want to [freely upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 10](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/windows-7-and-8-1-pcs-will-get-direct-upgrade-to-windows-10-1278884).

Will the procedure have some impact on the multi-boot structure that I should know about?

As [JourneymanGeek](https://superuser.com/users/10165/journeyman-geek) reminded me in the comment, the grub will be removed. It happened often, even when installing a new Linux system. I can reinstall Grub.

What about other things? I remember something about a Win10 feature not really shutting down the usual way, but just 'hibernating' instead or something, and that giving some problems in Linux (hard drives not mounting as far as I remember)...

---

UPDATE:

Following [this solution to make a full shutdown in Windows 10 without disabling hybrid boot](http://www.howtogeek.com/129021/how-to-do-a-full-shutdown-in-windows-8-without-disabling-hybrid-boot/) involving the command `shutdown /s /t 0`, the instalation partition of Windows 10 is not available in Linux:

[image]

The error message says that Windows is still in hibernation mode. So, that is not a full shut down.

The same happens after disabling hybrid boot completely, as indicated [here](https://superuser.com/a/656468/162573).

Comment: There's a pretty good chance it'll overwrite your current bootloader. As such, I am fairly doubtful that there will be *no* impact. As with any major update, backups and pre-planning is a good idea!

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - please take a look at my updated question

Comment: You need to shutdown Windows 10 the same way you shutdown Windows 8.1/8.0 you can create a shortcut in order to do this.  You can also just disable the hybrid shutdown if you want.

Comment: @Ramhound - I use Windows 7. Could you link to more details?

Comment: @cipricus - If after you do some research on the subject, you still cannot figure it out on your own, I will be happy to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only two problems I encountered where those mentioned in the comments above:

**1. Grub is removed, and no other OS except Windows 10 is thus accessible**.

**2. Windows 10 uses the Hybrid Boot feature, which basically hibernates instead of shutting down the system, and this may cause problems with multi-boot in Linux (windows partitions not accessible).**

---

So:

---

**1. In order to restore Grub**, boot in a live USB and install [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). In Ubuntu:

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair&&sudo apt-get
>   update&&sudo apt-get install boot-repair

Because I use a customized grub list (customized with Grub Customizer in one of my Linux systems) and because I wanted that list restored, I preferred the advanced options to re-install grub on that specific Linux system

(unimportant notice: the example image is not in a live session, where the "OS now in use" specification will be absent)

[image]

while un-checking the option to purge grub

[image]

Not purging grub is also a shorter and simpler process.

---

**2. To access Windows partition from Linux Win10 hibernation/hybrid boot has to be avoided.**

I first tried [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/129021/how-to-do-a-full-shutdown-in-windows-8-without-disabling-hybrid-boot/) solution to create a shortcut in Windows that would run the command

> ```
> shutdown /s /t 0
> ```

to do a full shut down (without disabling hybrid boot for the normal shutdown command).

But that didn't work, as indicated in the updated question, nor did fully disabling hybrid boot as indicated [here](https://superuser.com/a/656468/162573).

What worked was [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/457401/47206) to completely disable hibernation - source [here](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/12/disable-hibernation-windows-8/):

Winkey-X : Command Prompt (Admin).

Run:

> powercfg /h off