# Windows 10 setting for full shutdown?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

Apparently, in Windows 10 doing a SHUTDOWN from the Windows Start Menu, in reality performs a **hybrid shutdown** instead of a full shutdown! This sometimes seems to create problems when running Windows 10 in a Parallels Virtual Machine.

Where can I activate a setting for doing a FULL shutdown each time I shutdown from the Windows Start Menu?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disabling Hybrid Boot In Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/656459/disabling-hybrid-boot-in-windows-8)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Disable "fast start-up" under:

Control Panel > Power Options > "Change what the power buttons do"

[image]

If you *always* use the start menu, you can also hold shift while clicking the power icon and then "Shutdown".

## So what is this "fast start-up" thing anyway?

To quote Microsoft:

> The Fast Startup feature in Windows 10 allows your computer start up faster after a shutdown. When you shut down your computer, Fast Startup will put your computer into a hibernation state instead of a full shutdown. Fast Startup is enabled by default if your computer is capable of hibernation.

#### Edit with addition from Modelmat in the comments:

Fast Startup results in a "Hybrid Shutdown", where system/kernel level processes are hibernated, but user level programs are closed as normal. This creates the illusion of a full shutdown, but enables the system to be ready for use faster.

Comment: `all running programs are saved in their current state and then resume`. 
Strictly speaking this is not the case with a hybrid shutdown, windows still closes all user-level programs. Only kernel-level and similar programs are hibernated, which reduces boot time.

This is true with a windows "hibernation", which you can perform manually.

Comment: Thanks Modelmat, that's news to me - I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

You can also disable the fast startup through the Registry:
in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Power` key set
**HiberbootEnabled** value to **0** (type REG_DWORD).

This method is useful in corporate environment if you need to do it on many machines.

Setting the value to 1 enables fast startup.